# Icon in Windows Explorer showing 2 different icons when using resource.rc

Tags: c++, winapi, embedded-resource

I'm trying to change the icon of my Windows application. I'm using the simple window code below and added a `resource.h` and `resource.rc` to the solution. I'm using a `test.ico` and a `test2.ico`-file which both contain 64x64, 32x32, 24x24 and 16x16 sizes.

The when I switch between icon and icon2 by simple changing this line `TESTICON ICON "test.ico"` to `TESTICON ICON "test2.ico"` in the .rc-file, the icons change accordingly in program header bar, taskbar and alt-tab view. But the icon in my windows explorer is acting totally strange. When I set the view to details,list or small I see the `test.ico`-icon, but for medium, large and extra large I see the `test2.ico`-icon, no matter what I set in the .rc-file. I'm totally lost here, which setting am I missing?

The 'resource.h'

```
#pragma once
#define TESTICON 1
```

and the 'resource.rc'

```cpp
#include "resource.h"
TESTICON ICON "test.ico"
```

The simple windows source:

```cpp
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASSEX wc = { };

    //Step 1: Registering the Window Class
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = 0;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(hInstance,
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(TESTICON), IMAGE_ICON,
        ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON),
        ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON), 0);
    wc.hIconSm = (HICON)LoadImage(hInstance,
         MAKEINTRESOURCE(TESTICON), IMAGE_ICON,
        ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON),
        ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON), 0);

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    // Create the window.
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.
    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Explorer has an icon cache; if it's showing the wrong icon you probably need to clear the cache. https://leodavidson.blogspot.com/2011/05/clear-icon-cache-1001.html

Comment: It always presents me with the *"test.ico"* whatever view I change in file explorer. Could you show more information and steps for reproducing this issue?

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks for the tips, I'll check that out. It kinda drove me insane at some point.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT the example .rc-file shows test.ico indeed. I change this manually to test2.ico

Comment: Yes, I know that but I can't reproduce what you mentioned *"When I set the view to details,list or small I see the test.ico-icon, but for medium, large and extra large I see the test2.ico-icon, no matter what I set in the .rc-file."* Could you show some snapshots to demonstrate what you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Jonathan Potter: Explorer has an icon cache; if it's showing the wrong icon you probably need to clear the cache.
http://leodavidson.blogspot.com/2011/05/clear-icon-cache-1001.html

Comment: Hi mca2, feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).